# Actionscript: Passing public variable from one class to another?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash, variables, public

I'm stuck on creating a hit detection function inside an object class file so if it collides with the player on the stage it detects it. However i'm getting "Error:1067 Access of undefined property" for the public variables I call from the document class file.
Here is the function inside the object class I want to call public variables for:

```
public function hitTesting(obj:Object) {

    if (hitTestPoint(obj.x + leftBumpPoint.x, obj.y + pubVarsleftBumpPoint.y, true)) {
        trace("leftCollide");
        leftCollide = true;


    } else {
        leftCollide = false;
    }

    if (hitTestPoint(obj.x + rightBumpPoint.x, obj.y + rightBumpPoint.y, true)) {
        trace("right hit");
        rightCollide = true;
    } else {
        rightCollide = false;
    }

    if (hitTestPoint(obj.x + upBumpPoint.x, obj.y + upBumpPoint.y, true)) {
        trace("up hit");
        upCollide = true;
    } else {
        upCollide = false;
    }

}
```

edit:
Code for document class:

```
package {

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import MediumEnemy;

    public class PublicVariables extends MovieClip {

        public var upPressed: Boolean = false;
        public var downPressed: Boolean = false;
        public var leftPressed: Boolean = false;
        public var rightPressed: Boolean = false;
        public var xSpeed: Number = 0;
        public var ySpeed: Number = 0;
        public var gravity: Number = 1;
        public var scrollX: Number = 0;
        public var scrollY: Number = 0;
        public var speedConstant: int = 8;
        public var friction: Number = 0.55;
        public var leftCollide: Boolean = false;
        public var rightCollide: Boolean = false;
        public var upCollide: Boolean = false;
        public var downCollide: Boolean = false;
        public var leftBumpPoint: Point = new Point(-30, -55);
        public var rightBumpPoint: Point = new Point(30, -55);
        public var upBumpPoint: Point = new Point(0, -120);
        public var downBumpPoint: Point = new Point(0, 80);
        public var jumpConstant: Number = -65;
        public var gravityConstant: Number = 5;


        public function PublicVariables() {
```

Code for object class:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import PublicVariables;


    public class MediumEnemy extends PublicVariables {
        //private var xSpeed: Number = 8 //randomValue(3, 6); //not being used
        //private var ySpeed: Number = 8 //randomValue(8, 15); not being used
        private var direction: Boolean = false;



        public function MediumEnemy(xLocation: Number, yLocation: Number) {

            x = xLocation + randomValue(0, 550);
            y = yLocation; //set x position to random value


            if (x < 275) //determine whether to make the direction of motion left or right
            {
                direction = true
                //trace("go left")

            } else {
                direction = false;
                //trace("go right");
            }



            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate); //add this
        }



            function animate(event: Event) { //looping code

                switch (direction) {
                    case false:
                        {
                            x -= xSpeed;
                            break;
                        }
                    case true: //go right
                        {
                            x += xSpeed;

                            break;
                        }
                }
                y += ySpeed;


}





            public function hitTesting(obj: Object) {

            if (hitTestPoint(obj.x + leftBumpPoint.x, obj.y + leftBumpPoint.y, true)) {
                trace("leftCollide");
                leftCollide = true;


            } else {
                leftCollide = false;
            }

            if (hitTestPoint(obj.x + rightBumpPoint.x, obj.y + rightBumpPoint.y, true)) {
                trace("right hit");
                rightCollide = true;
            } else {
                rightCollide = false;
            }

            if (hitTestPoint(obj.x + upBumpPoint.x, obj.y + upBumpPoint.y, true)) {
                trace("up hit");
                upCollide = true;
            } else {
                upCollide = false;
            }

        }


    }

}
```

FYI: I was intending on somehow passing the 'player' object into the hitTesting function to get its x position using the parameter.

Comment: Could you share some more code? Will be necessary to understand the structure of both classes that you want to be able to send/receive data.

Comment: I've editted it to include variable definitions and stuff. There's quite a lot of code so if you need more just ask. Thanks so much for your reply.

Comment: Could you try changing this line: public class MediumEnemy extends MovieClip to public class MediumEnemy extends PublicVariables ? Let me know if you will get what you are looking for.

Comment: It appears to accept passing variables from PublicVariables however it doesn't appear to animate the object anymore?

Comment: Probably will be necessary to understand your entire logic for these two classes.

Comment: I've updated the code to contain all of the object class's code. The document class has no code in the body of its function. Its just got public variables.

Comment: Do you have some more code in the class PublicVariables?

Comment: No its just for public variables at this point.

Comment: I added an answer using an approach that I created an instance of PublicVariables in the object MediumEnemy. If you want it to be like 'global' Variable. I do recommend you to use static proprieties instead.

Answer (score 1):

To suggest you a good approach will be necessary to analyse your code and understand what could cause issues, etc.

Try this:

```
public class MediumEnemy extends MovieClip {
    private var direction:Boolean = false;
    private var publicVariables:PublicVariables = new PublicVariables();

    public function MediumEnemy(xLocation:Number, yLocation:Number) {
        x = xLocation + randomValue(0, 550);
        y = yLocation; // set x position to random value

        if (x < 275) // determine whether to make the direction of motion left or right
        {
            direction = true;
            // trace("go left")
        } else {
            direction = false;
            // trace("go right");
        }

        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate); // add this
    }

    private function animate(event:Event) { // looping code
        switch (direction) {
            case false: {
                x -= publicVariables.xSpeed;
                break;
            }
            case true: // go right
            {
                x += publicVariables.xSpeed;

                break;
            }
        }
        y += publicVariables.ySpeed;
    }

    public function hitTesting(obj:Object) {
        if (hitTestPoint(obj.x + publicVariables.leftBumpPoint.x, obj.y + publicVariables.leftBumpPoint.y, true)) {
            trace("leftCollide");
            publicVariables.leftCollide = true;
        } else {
            publicVariables.leftCollide = false;
        }

        if (hitTestPoint(obj.x + publicVariables.rightBumpPoint.x, obj.y + publicVariables.rightBumpPoint.y, true)) {
            trace("right hit");
            publicVariables.rightCollide = true;
        } else {
            publicVariables.rightCollide = false;
        }

        if (hitTestPoint(obj.x + publicVariables.upBumpPoint.x, obj.y + publicVariables.upBumpPoint.y, true)) {
            trace("up hit");
            publicVariables.upCollide = true;
        } else {
            publicVariables.upCollide = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Now its saying the .swf contains invalid data apparently. Thank you again for your reply. :)

Comment: Edit your code to the original state and analyse my example, to see how the interaction between MediumEnemy and PublicVariables works, to be able to make the proper change in your code.